# EntityManager.find returns previously deleted entity

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have code like the following, which fails the last assertion:

```
@Transactional
void foo()
{
  Assert.assertNotNull(em.find(TrivialEntity.class, 1));
  Assert.assertEquals(em.createQuery("DELETE TrivialEntity WHERE id=1").executeUpdate(), 1);
  Assert.assertNull(em.find(TrivialEntity.class, 1)); // fails
}
```

However, after running this code and checking the database, I see the entity was deleted. I'm guessing the second "find" statement is simply returning the previously returned result from the first "find".

I've also tried the code above with "em.flush" after the first and second statements above with no changes to the result. Code like the following does work, but I don't want to use "remove":

```
@Transactional
void foo()
{
  Assert.assertNotNull(em.find(TrivialEntity.class, 1));
  em.remove(em.find(TrivialEntity.class, 1));
  Assert.assertNull(em.find(TrivialEntity.class, 1)); // now it passes
}
```

Comment: Did you try to commit the transaction? With flush() the changes to the data are reflected in database, but it is still in transaction.

Comment: @AlexisPavlidis I am using "@Transactional", so the transaction is committed when the method successfully returns. I've confirmed that the entity is deleted from the DB after either of the above methods successfully return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way EntityManager works is that it handles only managed entities.

In the first case where you are removing TrivialEntity object by executing delete query by means of createQuery, No TrivialEntity object is associated with entityManager.

The reason it works later, You use find to retrieve Trivial Entity Object which indirectly associate it entityManager, remove works this time.

For more info [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)

> In order to delete an object from the db it has to first be
>   retrieved (no matter which way) and then in an active transaction, it
>   can be deleted using the remove method.
>
> An IllegalArgumentException is thrown by remove if the argument is not
>   a an instance of an entity class or if it is a detached entity.

Comment: I just found the following too, from https://www.baeldung.com/delete-with-hibernate#deletion-using-a-jpql-statement: " is important to note that DML-style JPQL statements affect neither the state nor life cycle of entity instances that are already loaded into the persistence context"